# Undefined Reference to non-member operators from dll

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt-creator

For an assignment I created a fractions class that overloads many operators. I then converted it into a dll to be used by another program. The issue I am having is that when I try to use the non-member operators I get the error "undefined reference to 'operator+'".

I believe I have implemented the dll correctly as the constructors works correctly as do any member functions/operators. Just the non-member operators are giving me this issue.

```
        Fraction frac1(1,5); //No errors
        Fraction frac2(2,5); //No errors
        Fraction frac3 = frac2 + frac1; //ERROR: undefined reference to 'operator+'
        //Note: + operator is a non-member operator
        frac2 += frac1; //No errors and is a member operator
```

I've been trying to solve this and googling for hours with no success. It could possible be a linking issue but I have had no luck figuring that out if so.

I'm using Qt Creator (since I am implenting a GUI) and MinGW.

Comment: Did you add a __declspec(export)/__declspec(import) in front of the out of class operators?

Comment: I have not, I haven't heard of that before. Would I simply do frac2 __declspec(import)+ frac1? @MorningDewd

Comment: If you want to expose functions or classes to an dll, you have to 'tag' them with the declspec. Same if you want the linker to know that symbols found in a header file will come from a .dll. See this link for a tutorial http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version: you need to properly export/import our library objects and code.

---

Long Version:

Somewhere in your header will be a macro definition similar to the following:

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(export)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(import)
#endif
```

This macro is later used in a variety of places in the header, and implementation files. For example, a simple function is declared like this:

```
MYDLL_API int MyFunction(int);
```

or as another example, an entire class and its members likewise can be exported:

```
class MYDLL_API MyClass
{
    // members...
};
```

When compiling your DLL (i.e building the actual DLL project), a preprocessor macro, `MYDLL_EXPORTS`, is defined either in a primary project-only header (NOT the dll expose' header) or on the actual build command. This, in turn, makes all `MYDLL_API` decorated symbols "exported". I.e., using our API example above, this:

```
MYDLL_API int MyFunction(int);
```

becomes this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int MyFunction(int);
```

When consuming the header and DLL import library, do NOT define the `MYDLL_EXPORTS` macro, and in turn the same function decl in the header now looks like this:

```
__declspec(dllimport) int MyFunction(int);
```

Ok. That's a lot of information or what ultimately comes down to this. You have a free-function operator that is declared, but not exported, in your DLL. I.e. given all of the above, you have a class `Fraction` that probably looks like this:

```
class MYDLL_API Fraction
{
    // members
};
```

and also a free-function operator that looks like this:

```
Fraction operator +(Fraction, Fraction);
```

The latter should look like this:

```
MYDLL_API Fraction operator +(Fraction, Fraction)
```